# How can people with the same native language and target language practice with each other?

Tags: learning-methods, self-learning, learning-psychology

In this thread Dr @[Rebecca J. Stones](https://languagelearning.stackexchange.com/users/2795/rebecca-j-stones) raised [a very interesting question](https://languagelearning.stackexchange.com/q/5640/4697) on the reasons behind Chinese people who are eager to practice English don't simply practice with each other, and I've [shared my experiences there](https://languagelearning.stackexchange.com/a/6050/4697). However, what I am eager to know is how we can practice English that way efficiently and sustainably. And I also like to broaden the scope to all language learners with the same native language and target language.

Comment: An important factor is the environment. You need an environment where the participants are of similar motivation and of similar level, and you need an instructor/guide who will facilitate/encourage people to take an active learning role. In my experience, this comes more naturally in an in-person environment (not online). For online forums, it may be possible but may require more effort or creativity.

Comment: There is not much point having two A language speakers speak another (B) language to one another. You have to find someone to talk to in English.